# Invalid JSON primitive: Date

Tags: c#, html, json, json.net

I keep getting the following error: "Invalid JSON primitive: Date".  I am not sure how to correct as I have changes to the front/back-end of the project.  Everything seems to be working other than when I de-bug the JavaScript. My front-end code is as follows (I only included some HTML, where a date is used):

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
    runat="server">
   <script>
    $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            "dataSource": {
                "transport": {
                    "read": {
                        "url": "CreateReq.aspx/PopulateMessages",//page then function
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        "data": {
                            requestID: document.getElementById("lblRequestID").textContent
                        } 
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "CreateReq.aspx/CreateMessage",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        "data": {

                        }

                    },
                    "prefix": ""
                },
                "schema": {
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response.d;
                    },
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Date: { type: "date",editable: false, format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}", encoded: true, /*defaultValue: Date.now*/ },
                            Author: { type: "string", editable: true},
                            Message: { type: "string" }, 

                        }

                    }
                },
            },
            //pageable: true,
            height: 225,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [

                { field: "Date", title: "Date", width: "75px", /*template: '#= kendo.toString((Date), "MM/dd/yyyy")#'*/ format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}", encoded: true},
                { field: "Author", title: "Author", width: "75px" },
                { field: "Message", title: "Message", width: "300px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
            editable: "inline"
        });
    });

</script>

<h1 style="text-align: center">Academic Code Request</h1>
<div class="TopPageButtons" style="text-align: center">

        <br />
</div>

<div class="TrackingBox">
    <div class="TrBoxContent">
        <div>
            <label><b>ID</b></label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblRequestID" Text="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label><b>Form View Date</b></label><br />

            <asp:TextBox ID="RequestDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="text-align:center"/>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("RequestDate").value = new Date().toString();
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: @juharr, where is the trailing comma?

Comment: This part `Date: { type: "date",editable: false, format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}", encoded: true, /*defaultValue: Date.now*/ }` will result in `Date: { type: "date",editable: false, format: "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}", encoded: true, }` with a trailing comma after `true`.

Comment: @juharr, I removed the comments from my code.  I do not see any extra comma.

Comment: @juharr, I removed the comma, but still get the following error - "Invalid JSON primitive: Date".

Comment: Can you try quoting the field names in schema, model, fields? It may be misinterpreting the Date there as the JavaScript Date class. (I assume you're running this exactly as-is, and not e.g. uncommenting-out the defaultValue there etc.)

Comment: @Rup I am not sure I follow the suggestion to quote filed names in schema.  I am not familiar with JS/JSON syntax.

Comment: I meant your object structure: you've got `{ "dataSource": { "schema": { model: { fields: { Date: { ...` and the line with the `Date` is about half-way down your pasted code. I meant change that to `"Date"`.

Comment: @Rup, Should date, author, and message be in quotes or just date?

Comment: I'd guess Date is the problematic one since there is a JavaScript Date class. The others can be, but might not matter.

Comment: @Rup, I made the change and get the same error.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Can you work out which part of this is causing the error? I assume you don't get a useful line number with the error or anything? Can you try deleting all the contents of the object you're passing to kendoGrid, i.e. just call it with `{}`, and see if you still get the error? If you don't, try putting back sections one at a time or a few at a time and see when you get the error again.

Comment: @Rup, there was no line number.  When yoou say to removed the object contents, are you referring to the field contents?

Comment: No, I meant the contents of the object that you're passing as the argument to the kendoGrid() call. You're passing it `{ "dataSource": {...}, height: 225, ... }` which is creating an object with keys dataSource, height, toolbar etc. I assume something in there, or something in the dataSource object inside that, is causing this error. I'm suggesting you try removing items from that, from the object that you're constructing as the argument to the kendoGrid call, to try and narrow down which line or lines in there is causing the error.

Comment: @Rup I have not pinpointed the cause.

Comment: I guess another option then is that the AJAX services that you’re passing by URL are returning bad content. Can you look at the data they’re returning e.g. in your browsers developer tools and check that that is valid JSON, especially no stray unquoted ‘Date’ as a value field? But if that’s not it either then I’m afraid I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Actually one more idea: use an unminifed version on kendoGrid and see if you can get your browser to break for debugging at the point it throws the error. Then look for context there.